# Child element fixed position and 100% width of parrent

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I have child element sidebar  and i'd like to set him **100% width** of **parent** element. That works without **fixed position**. But also i need fixed position for "collapse/expand" function.

`.non-active{left: -250px;}` Parent element is maximum 250px of width;

**Javascript collapse/expand**

```
   $(".close-btn").click(function () {
      $(".side-bar").addClass("non-active");
      $(".menu-btn").css("visibility", "visible");
    });

    $(".menu-btn").click(function () {
      $(".side-bar").removeClass("non-active");
      $(".menu-btn").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
```

**Sidebar.html**

```
<div class="menu-btn">
  <i class="fas fa-bars vertical"></i>
</div>
  <div class="side-bar">
    <div class="close-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-times vertical"></i>
    </div>
    <h1>Doučování</h1>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item">
        <a class="sub-btn">
          Matice
          <i class="fas fa-angle-right dropdown"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <a
            href="/pages/matice/zakladni-operace.html"
            id="matice/zakladni-operace"
            onClick="reply_click(this.id)"
            class="sub-item">
            Základní operace
          </a>
          <a
            href="/pages/matice/hodnosti.html"
            id="matice/hodnosti"
            onClick="reply_click(this.id)"
            class="sub-item">
            Hodnost
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Sidebar.css**

```
.side-bar {
  background: #1b1a1b;
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  transition-property: left;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain little detail?

Comment: for me, fixed of parent doesn't mean anything. Fixed is: "The element is removed from the normal document flow..." Meaning what you think is its parent is not.

Comment: It would help everyone if you were to edit your question and use the snippet tool `<>` to load your html and css